# Can't get a Session after OAuth with Linear

Tags: authentication, next.js, oauth-2.0, oauth, next-auth

It seems like I'm logging in and I get a code that should return a token. Token is in the cookie in Session, but the session is an empty object. I tried to console.log callbacks, but I got nothing in return. I don't get any errors either, just an empty session.

I tried to debug it, but I always get redirected to https://eqeq2e2-152-115-126-50.ngrok-free.app/callback?code=somecode7eg187e2g&state=stateobsaoisf3f23 and "Access denied" coming from !session.

I'm using ngrok, because localhost can't be used in Linear url.

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";

import Auth0Provider from "next-auth/providers/auth0";

export default NextAuth({
  providers: [
    Auth0Provider({
      id: "linear",
      name: "Linear",
      type: "oauth",
      authorization: {
        url: "https://linear.app/oauth/authorize",
        params: {
          scope: "read",
          approval_prompt: "consent",
          response_type: "code",
          redirect_uri: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_URL}`,
        },
      },
      token: {
        url: "https://api.linear.app/oauth/token",
        params: {
          grant_type: "authorization_code",
          redirect_uri: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_URL}`,
        },
      },

      userinfo: {
        url: "https://api.linear.app/graphql",
        async request(context) {
          const res = await fetch("https://api.linear.app/graphql", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${context.tokens.access_token}`,
              "User-Agent": "authjs",
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: '{"query":"{ viewer { id name email avatarUrl description} }"}',
          });
          const data = await res.json();
          return {
            id: data.data.viewer.id,
            name: data.data.viewer.name,
            email: data.data.viewer.email,
            avatarUrl: data.data.viewer.avatarUrl,
            description: data.data.viewer.description,
          };
        },
      },
      async profile(profile) {
        return {
          id: profile.id,
          name: profile.name,
          email: profile.email,
          image: profile.avatarUrl,
        };
      },
      clientId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_LINEAR_CLIENT_SECRET,
      //   issuer: process.env.NAUTH0_ISSUER,
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async signIn({ user, account, profile, email, credentials }) {
      try {
        console.log("signin");
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error during token exchange:", error);
      }

      return true;
    },
    async redirect({ url, baseUrl, user }) {
      console.log("redirect");
      if (user && user.id) {
        return `/user/${user.id}`;
      }

      return url.startsWith(baseUrl) ? url : baseUrl;
    },
    async jwt({ token, account }) {
      console.log("JWT callback - Token:", token);
      console.log("JWT callback - User:", user);
      console.log("JWT callback - Account:", account);
      if (account?.accessToken) {
        console.log("JWT callback - Access Token:", account.accessToken);
        token.accessToken = account.accessToken;
      }
      return token;
    },
    async session({ session, token }) {
      console.log("Session callback - Session:", session);
      console.log("Session callback - Token:", token);
      session.accessToken = token.accessToken;
      return session;
    },
  },
  //   session: {
  //     strategy: "jwt",
  //   },
  session: async (session, userOrToken) => {
    if (userOrToken.accessToken) {
      session.accessToken = userOrToken.accessToken;
    }
    return session;
  },
  logger: {
    error(code, metadata) {
      console.error(code, metadata);
    },
    warn(code) {
      console.warn(code);
    },
    debug(code, metadata) {
      console.debug(code, metadata);
    },
  },
});
```

```
import { BlueButton } from "@/components/reusable/Button";
import { Formik, Form, Field, ErrorMessage } from "formik";
import * as Yup from "yup";

// Validation schema for the login form
const LoginSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  email: Yup.string().email("Invalid email").required("Required"),
  password: Yup.string().required("Required"),
});

const Login = () => {
  const RANDOM_STATE =
    Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15) +
    Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15);

  const OAUTH_URL = `https://linear.app/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CLIENT_ID}&redirect_uri=${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_URL}/callback&scope=read,write&state=${RANDOM_STATE}`;

  return (
    <div className="h-[440px] w-[400px] mx-auto mt-20 bg-light_blue_e flex flex-col justify-center rounded-[20px] px-20 font-aileron">
      <p className="text-xl text-white">Log in to your account</p>
      >
      <button
        onClick={() => (window.location.href = OAUTH_URL)}
        className="mt-4 bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded"
      >
        Log in with Linear
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useSession } from "next-auth/react";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

const Callback = () => {
  const { data: session, status } = useSession();
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (status === "authenticated" && session?.user?.id) {
      // Redirect to the dynamic user page
      router.push(`/user/${session.user.id}`);
    }
  }, [session, status, router]);

  if (status === "loading") {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  if (!session) {
    return <div>Access denied!</div>;
  }

  // Render your callback page content here
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Callback</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Callback;
```

I tried changing types of provider, content of callbacks and console.logs in callbacks, changing url to api/auth/callback/linear as suggested in docs.
I was expecting to get a session and token that allows me to fetch data from this linear user.